# How do I make grep -f find the specific pattern I am looking for?

Tags: csv, grep

I am trying to pull a sublist of patterns out from a bigger file, but when I try grep -f file1.csv file2.csv > output.csv I am getting too much of the pattern, and when I try grep -w -f file1 file2 > output I am getting too little of the pattern. The reason why I am getting too much of the pattern is because I will have:

```
G100,
G1001,
S4000,
S40001
```

in file 2 and I just want to pull out G100 and S4000. Is there any way to make grep even more specific, so that I just pull out G100 and S4000? Any help much appreciated, as I am just an amateur. Thanks!

Comment: What's in `file1.csv`/`file1`? What is "too much"? What is "too little"?

Comment: File1 contains a list of things, so G100, G1001, G1002, G1003, G1004, S100, S101, S102 ...etc. in csv format. I want to extract the list in File1 from File2, but when I do "grep -f" that it gives me too many things because there are similarities in the list as you can see from G100, G1001. When I do grep -w -f, I expect to extract all of file1 from file2, but instead I do not get all of file1 from file2. Hope this helps!

Comment: What entries **specifically** from `file2(.csv)` are you missing when you use `grep -w -f file1 file2`? Please include **exact** contents of `file1` and `file2` and **exact** missing matches in your post.